# Errors when creating django project in pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm, manage.py

I am a beginner in python and pycharm, I want to create a Django project under pycharm but when I click on the create button I got this errors: 
knowing that I am using the latest version of pycharm (2019.1)

```
Error creating Django application: Error on python side. Exit code: 1, err: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\hanan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\hanan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "E:\django_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\hanan\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\hanan\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module is not found.
 out:
```

Thank's in advance :)

Comment: Don't use Anaconda as a base for pure Python virtual environment. Either use conda environment or pure Python (e.g. from python.org) as a base for venv.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you trying to create a Django project in PyCharm?

The official Django docs have an easy to follow guide on how to setup your first Django app using the terminal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows as your OS? It seems that you're problem is related to  sqlite3. Maybe downloading and installing precompiled version will fixed your issue.

Download and installation instruction can be found here: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

And also check your system PATH value and add sqlite3 path to it if not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much @dRHossein, it worked . Bless you :)